# Removing light source on a reflective surface

Tags: light

I want to have a reflective floor, but have it not reflect rays coming from a light. Using Blender 2.91, Cycles. I want the light to create a glossy rim light on the object in the scene, so I don't the usual solution of Light > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Glossy off cannot be applied here.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *Mesh* light object use *Point* or *Sun* that generate much smaller light source ...

[image]

... to hide from render entirely change *Size* under *Light  Properties* to zero.

[image]